# How to parse TSV data into nested objects

Tags: univocity

I'm trying to parse the following TSV data into a nested object but my "title" field is always null within the Nested class.

I've included the method at the bottom which converts the TSV data to the object.

```
value1 | metaData1 | valueA |
value2 | metaData2 | valueB |
value3 | metaData3 | valueC |
```

---

```
public class Data {
    @Parsed(index = 0)
    private String value0;

    @Parsed(index = 1)
    private String foo;

    @Nested
    MetaData metaData;

    public static class MetaData {
        @Parsed(index = 1)
        private String title;
    }
}
```

---

```
public <T> List<T> convertFileToData(File file, Class<T> clazz, boolean removeHeader) {

    BeanListProcessor<T> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<>(clazz);
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.getFormat().setDelimiter('|');
    settings.setProcessor(rowProcessor);
    settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(removeHeader);

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    parser.parseAll(file);

    return rowProcessor.getBeans();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to define an `index` on your `Metadata.title`:

```
public static class MetaData {
    @Parsed(index=1)
    private String title;
}
```

Also, you are setting the delimiter to `\t` while your input is using `|` as the separator.

Comment: When I use index=1, then I it works, I get a value in the title attribute, however, when I use index=2 then I get null which is odd.                             I've updated the question to remove the \t, that was a typo.

Comment: I tried setting index = 2 in `Metadata.title` and it worked. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: I've updated to the latest version and it is working. thanks!   One thing I had to do to make it work though is I had to add the index I wanted to use to the nested class in the outer class first. I've updated the original question so you can see this -- look at attribute "foo".  Is this how it is suppose to work?

Comment: If I take attribute foo out, then I get null in the title attribute in the inner class.